# Preventing all-caps question titles and bodies

Tags: feature-request, filtering

I believe that already, there are some words that are mechanically forbidden in StackOverflow question titles. The words “question” and “problem” must be two, because you sometimes see them spelt strangely in order to circumvent the protection.

Something that I think would be useful, that correspond to somewhat common behavior of newcomers, that would not be circumventable, and that would not have many false positives (i.e. prevent legitimate questions) would be automatic detection of question titles or bodies made of more than 50% of capital letters.

Exceptions could be made for tags corresponding to old languages that may be programmed in uppercase out of tradition (FORTRAN, COBOL, BASIC).

What do people think?

Comment: WE SHOULD DEFINITELY IMPLEMENT THIS. (You had to have seen that coming...)

Comment: "that would not be circumventable" cAPS lOCK + sHIFT CAN DO WONDERS.

Comment: @BoltClock You are still over 50%, AlThOuGh It Is PoSsIbLe To bE ReAlLy AnNoYiNg BeLoW ThIs LiMiT ToO.

Comment: Oh I missed the part where you said 50%. Actually a reasonable threshold now that I think about it.

Comment: Really only the first letter of each sentence + proper nouns + acronyms require caps, so maybe 25% could be used instead?

Comment: All-caps titles are highly associated with poor question quality. You would remove that signal that a closer look is needed?

Comment: @Sam “Generating XHTML in FORTRAN”

Comment: @PascalCuoq Ah, didn't know about that. What about if text as code were to be ignored?

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta I would say that all-caps titles **make** questions poor quality. A fair proportion of them are fine once uncapitalized. Or were you being sarcastic?

Comment: Waffles did an analysis of this a while back and determined it wasn't worthwhile at all; plus I _think_ that this is a heuristic caught by the low quality filter. Even without that all caps questions get either fixed or down voted to oblivion almost immediately. Is this really a problem?

Comment: @Sam First, backticks do not work in titles. Second, if they did and backtick text was not counted, people would write everything between backticks to circumvent the protection, and the end result would be worse.

Comment: MSE dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/121301/179419

Comment: Not sarcastic at all, and I strongly disagree that sentence-casing an all-caps title would make the affected question all right. Not in my experience - the problems continue down into the meat of the question.

Comment: @Ben It is only one paper cut.

Comment: @PascalCuoq I was referring to this proposal's application to the body of a question (if that does happen also), not the title. But yeah, good point.

Comment: Why shouldn't we auto-capitalize ( I hope I didn't spell it wrongly ) and just ignore some filtered word - for example, BASIC, FORTRAN, COBOL, or something else?

Comment: @Jamie Because the results would be horrible. I spend my time correcting the spelling of “OCaml”, then it would be everyone who would have to correct anything from SIGCONT to LinuxThreads.

Comment: Can you show some examples of this actually happening? In all the years I only saw a hand full of them and I don't remember if making them normal case wasn't sufficient to make them not-delete-worthy.

Comment: @PlasmaHH This is a good point. The one that triggered my question was http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24588211 which I thought someone would answer, but since you asked, only http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24628162/ has come up, which is probably not worth salvaging.

Comment: @PlasmaHH Another all-caps title. I am not familiar with the subject but the question looks salvageable (i.e. someone may have to retype this title, whether the OP or someone else). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24700450/dropzone-js-not-working-on-server

Comment: @PlasmaHH Although the question was worthless, someone wasted their time editing this one, for instance: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24828372/how-to-get-a-list-of-processes-in-jbpm6

Comment: @PlasmaHH a question that would be ok except for the all caps title: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24974326/arm-assembly-program-error-this-register-combination-results-in-unpredictable

Comment: This one too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24987135/how-to-make-a-jquery-slider-loop

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33537519/how-to-know-particular-column-is-updated-or-not-in-oracle-11g-with-out-triggers And OP says he used CapsLock for the bold look ;-)

Comment: Hotfix: `#question-header { text-transform: lowercase } #question-header ::first-letter { text-transform: uppercase }` ***/s***